# How to fill ajax POST value in a form field?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, post

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content-area').mouseup(function() {
   var selection = getSelected();
   if(selection && (selection = new String(selection).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''))){
         $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url : 'check.php',
         data: 'selection=' + encodeURI(selection),
   });
   }
  });
```

Now how do I access the POSTed 'data' and fill a text field in HTML forms. I'm not clicking a button during the ajax post and I want to do it without reloading the entire page. Any help is much much appreciated..

Comment: are you talking about the data that comes back from the server?

Comment: @Leo yes, I want to access the 'selection' variable from the ajax post and fill the form text field after text is selected.

Comment: what kind of data are you expecting? `json`, `xml`, etc?

Comment: @Leo  Just a normal text string. I alerted the 'selection' variable and it works fine. But, I'm not fully aware of how to fill the text field from the POSTed value. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to define the a `success` handler in your ajax call. This handler will take three parameters, the first one is the data you are receiving back from the server...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content-area').mouseup(function() {
   var selection = getSelected();
   if(selection && (selection = new String(selection).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''))){
         $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url : 'check.php',
         data: 'selection=' + encodeURI(selection),
         success: function(data){
            alert(data.d);
            $('text_input_selector').val(data.d);
        }
   });
   }
  });
```

Notice that `text_input_selector` must be a valid selector of your text input

Answer (score 0):

Try below code sample :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#content-area').mouseup(function () {
        var selection = getSelected();

        if (selection && (selection = new String(selection).replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''))) {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'check.php',
                data: 'selection=' + encodeURI(selection),
                beforeSend: function () {
                    //do something
                }
                success: function (response) {
                    $("TEXTFIELD_ID").val(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Write Success callback handler. like

```
 $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url : 'check.php',
         data: 'selection=' + encodeURI(selection),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                var returnedvalue = result.d;
                debugger;
            },
```